# Probability that $ f$ out of $n$ ($f < n$) random events happen at the same time.

Tags: probability

Assuming we have $n$ random independent events, and the probability for each event is $P_i$ where $i \in n$. What is the probability that $f$ events, where $f < n$, happen at the same time?

Comment: Are the events dependent of independent?

Comment: @Moritz The events are independent.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Any combination of $f$ events out of the $n$ can occur. For each combination, the events selected happen with probability $P_i$, while the events not selected happen with probability $1-P_i$.

Since the events and non-events are independent, we multiply their probabilities. Since the combinations are mutually exclusive, we add *their* probabilities. Symbolically, the probability that exactly $f$ events out of $n$ occur is
$$\sum_{T\subset S;|T|=f}\left(\prod_{i\in T}P_i\right)\left(\prod_{j\in S\setminus T}(1-P_j)\right)$$
where $S=\{1,2,\dots,n\}$ is the set of the first $n$ natural numbers, and the sum is taken over all $f$-element subsets of $S$.

The expression above is the pmf of the sum of $n$ independent Bernoulli trials with success probabilities $P_i$, where $f$ is the realisation. We note that if all $P_i$ are the same, the distribution becomes binomial.

Comment: how would the formula change if the $f$ events can happen in a time interval $t$, for example if we replace "happen at the same time" with "happen at least once in a time interval $t$".